# Index not used in query - using EXPLAIN

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table named `datasourcedescription`
The table has approximately 1000 rows.
I created new composite index called `idx_datasourcedescription_dsd_prefix_dsd_type_id_dsd_hide`;

The table indexes look like this:

```
mysql> SHOW INDEXES FROM datasourcedescription;
+-----------------------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table                 | Non_unique | Key_name                                                  | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+-----------------------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| datasourcedescription |          0 | PRIMARY                                                   |            1 | dsd_prefix  | A         |         688 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| datasourcedescription |          0 | idx_datasourcedescription_dsd_prefix_dsd_type_id_dsd_hide |            1 | dsd_prefix  | A         |         688 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| datasourcedescription |          0 | idx_datasourcedescription_dsd_prefix_dsd_type_id_dsd_hide |            2 | dsd_type_id | A         |         688 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| datasourcedescription |          0 | idx_datasourcedescription_dsd_prefix_dsd_type_id_dsd_hide |            3 | dsd_hide    | A         |         688 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| datasourcedescription |          1 | datasourcedescription_dsd_type_id                         |            1 | dsd_type_id | A         |           8 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+-----------------------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
```

So, I wanted to test my newly created index ( `idx_datasourcedescription_dsd_prefix_dsd_type_id_dsd_hide`  ) with the following query:

`EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM csrhub_data_1.datasourcedescription where dsd_prefix = '3BL' and dsd_type_id = "NGO" and dsd_hide = "Yes"`;

The result is:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM csrhub_data_1.datasourcedescription where dsd_prefix = '3BL' and dsd_type_id = "NGO" and dsd_hide = "Yes";
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                                               |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | NULL  | NULL       | NULL | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | NULL |     NULL | Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

As @Akina suggested: The table structure looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `datasourcedescription` (
  `dsd_partner` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dsd_prefix` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `dsd_type_id` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dsd_update_routine` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dsd_update_frequency` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dsd_overall_weight` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `dsd_link` longtext,
  `dsd_logo` longblob,
  `dsd_description` text NOT NULL,
  `dsd_frequency` text NOT NULL,
  `dsd_number` text NOT NULL,
  `dsd_data_type` text NOT NULL,
  `dsd_custom_reports` text NOT NULL,
  `dsd_custom_report_price` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `dsd_additional` text,
  `dsd_date_added` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `dsd_date_updated` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `dsd_nid` int NOT NULL,
  `dsd_flag` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `dsd_search` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `dsd_header` text,
  `dsd_footer` text,
  `dsd_explanation_link` longtext,
  `dsd_minimum_data` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `dsd_hide` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dsd_prefix`),
  KEY `datasourcedescription_dsd_type_id` (`dsd_type_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

As you can see my new index is not utilized. Why?
What am I missing here?

**EDIT**
My query turned out to return empty set. So I changed it to

`EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM csrhub_data_1.datasourcedescription where dsd_prefix = '3BL' and dsd_type_id = 'PUB' and dsd_hide = 'No';`

EXPLAIN now results in

```
`+----+-------------+-----------------------+------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table                 | partitions | type  | possible_keys                                                                                       | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+-----------------------+------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | datasourcedescription | NULL       | const | PRIMARY,idx_datasourcedescription_dsd_prefix_dsd_type_id_dsd_hide,datasourcedescription_dsd_type_id | PRIMARY | 47      | const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+-----------------------+------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+`
```

Now PRIMARY index is used instead of the composite one.

Comment: Server tells that some conditional is inconsistent to your structure/data.

Comment: Provide the structure as complete CREATE TABLE script. After composite index creation, of course.

Comment: @Akina Could you elaborate little bit on that please

Comment: ... also provide table's data example (2-3 rows, if you can - in INSERT INTO form).

Comment: @Akina sorry the data is confidential - why do you need such a think?

Comment: *why do you need* I need to ensure that the values used in a query are (may at least) present in a table. Now maybe this is excess - you provide the structure, and datatypes allows shown values. *the data is confidential* The values of the columns used in your query cannot be confidential (at least I cannot imagine this).

Comment: PS. Try to replace double quotes with single quotes.

Comment: Your explain plan says "Impossible WHERE noticed..." Is your where clause always, as written, always false? -- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html

Comment: See this answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21220/why-am-i-getting-impossible-where-noticed-after-reading-const-tables-in-explai

Comment: @Akina replaced wit single quotes - same

Comment: Replace nevertheless. In MySQL dquote chars are used for JSON path/value quoting primarily.

Comment: I edited my original post based on some new findings

Comment: @Hairi - re  Confidentiality: Make up data _that is consistent with the Quesiton_.

Comment: @Akina - In MySQL single and double quotes are (I think) totally interchangeable.  (A possible exception is "Ascii quotes" mode.

Comment: re "Impossible WHERE" means that `EXPLAIN` did enough research to realize that (3BL, PUB, YES) did not exist in the table.  Hence, there was nothing left for `SELECT` to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  csrhub_data_1.datasourcedescription
    where  prefix = '3BL'
      and  type_id = 'PUB'
      and  hide = 'No';
```

might benefit from this "composite" index, with the columns in any order:

INDEX(hide, type_id, prefix)

BUT...  Since a `PRIMARY KEY` is, by definition (in MySQL) unique, this query does not make a lot of sense.  `prefix = '3BL'` is *sufficient* to locate the row; the other two tests nearly confirm that the row has the expected 'PUB' and 'No'. That is, the query will deliver either

- The one row determined by the unique prefix, or
- No rows (because the other tests fail)

The Optimizer decided that it would be faster simply to use the PK and then check the other two columns.

In general, it is 'never' beneficial to have the PK *first* in a secondary index.  (There may be obscure exceptions.)

(Nit pick: Get rid of the `dsd_`; it clutters and makes the important parts harder to see.)